# Installing PHP Modules in Docker for 2.3.4 Upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, docker, ubuntu

I've been working on upgrading my local environment from 2.2.10 to 2.3.4, but can't figure out how to install the extra PHP modules for the new version (ie: sodium) using Docker. I was previously using PHP 7.1, but just rebuilt my containers with 7.3. They're up and running with no problem, but how do I go about adding the modules? I tried running `sudo pecl install -f libsodium` which I thought would work, but because sodium wasn't added to the php.ini file it wasn't able to pick it up. I haven't been able to even find the .ini file inside the container, and am really at a loss here. The next thing I tried was adding it into the PHP Extensions line in docker-compose.yml, but this seems to break the ability to even run bin/magento from inside the container. [image]

Fyi I'm new to magento and docker, so I might be missing something obvious here. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to explain if you are new to docker

But essentially you need to add these components when you build the docker image

https://github.com/DominicWatts/docker-magento2/blob/master/php/src/7.3-fpm/Dockerfile

To build that docker image and push it to docker hub would do something like this

```
cd php/src/7.3-fpm

docker login

docker build -t domw/magento2-php:7.3-fpm ./

docker push domw/magento2-php:7.3-fpm
```

Then to use it in project docker compose

https://github.com/DominicWatts/docker-magento2/blob/cb96aca516e51a418db28b46f03723f336b74ccf/docker-compose.src.73.yml#L28-L39

```yaml
  fpm:
    hostname: fpm.magento2.docker
    image: domw/magento2-php:7.3-fpm
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - 9000
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./magento:/var/www/magento
    env_file:
      - ./global.env
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the informative response. This might be a dumb question, but since the image I'm pulling is from magento, how can I edit the original Dockerfile to include the modules I need? Do I need to clone the full magento docker to my github, alter the Dockerfile, then pull from this repo?

Comment: Can I take a look at docker image?

Comment: Here is the docker-compose.yml: https://pastebin.com/mXzX30DW, and I'm also using a docker-compose.override.yml file: https://pastebin.com/8giPFvtK. I don't have access to the Dockerfile itself, which I think may be one of the problems?

Comment: First time I'm seen an official(ish) docker compose file. Where did you get that from or did you put that together yourself? I put together my own stack https://github.com/DominicWatts/docker-magento2 but mine is a fork of the meanbee solution. I just got mine working how I wanted it and added some quick steps and bits and pieces. Performance was a big thing for me but I started this on windows. Now using linux (debian). But it's not the fastest and always having to look at permissions. But good enough for dev. Any time need something I add to docker file and rebuild and push to dockerhub

Comment: Well you've blown my mind. All the source files are here https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud-docker/tree/develop/images/php

Comment: Haha I'm glad I gave you a chance to check it out then. I actually got it from magento ece-tools. Running ```./vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose --mode="developer" --sync-engine="native"``` autogenerates it for you, then you just need to build the containers, import the db, and you're good to go. However this is the first time I'm trying to upgrade my magento version (currently on 2.2.10), and I'm running into so many issues regarding php version compatibility, and speed on my ubuntu VM is not exactly the greatest

Comment: Thanks for sharing your custom file, I'm wondering if I should use something like that rather than docker-compose since I'm not sure how to add anything still

Comment: Are you using it with community edition?

Comment: Nope, I'm using cloud enterprise which also adds to the complication

Comment: Yep that's one big difference. I pulled apart the official cloud docker and got open source running on it https://github.com/DominicWatts/Magento2CloudDocker you can see all the Dockerfiles involved. Hopefully that should give you a bit more understanding on how this all fits together.

Comment: Yes I've been looking through your repo and although I haven't fully solved this, you've helped fill in some missing pieces regarding the architecture. Thanks a lot for your help man